# JOIN multiple tables with results on the same column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, syntax

I have this table:

Table1

```
--------------------
id  |  category
--------------------
1   | Cat1
2   | Cat2
3   | Cat3
```

For each category, I have tables with subcategories, and the corresponding category ID, like this:

Table2

```
--------------------------------
id  | subcategory  | category_id
--------------------------------
1   | subcat1      |     1
2   | subcat2      |     1
3   | subcat3      |     1
4   | subcat4      |     1
```

Table3

```
--------------------------------
id  | subcategory  | category_id
--------------------------------
1   | subcat5      |     2
2   | subcat6      |     2
3   | subcat7      |     2
4   | subcat8      |     2
```

I want to query my data, so I get the following:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
category  | subcategory ( from Table2 and Table3)  
-----------------------------------------------------
Cat1      | subcat1      
Cat1      | subcat2      
Cat1      | subcat3      
Cat1      | subcat4
Cat2      | subcat5      
Cat2      | subcat6      
Cat2      | subcat7      
Cat2      | subcat8
Cat3      | NULL
```

I tried something like this, but it puts the data from each table on a new column.

```
SELECT Table1.category, Table2.subcategory  , Table3.subcategory  
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.id=Table2 .category_id
LEFT JOIN Table3 ON Table1.id=Table3.category_id
```

I'm a beginner.

Thank you!

Comment: t1 Left join (t2 UNION ALL t3)

Comment: This is a terrible design, why have one table per category instead of just one table?

Comment: @Lamak is right. If you are allowed to change the database design, do it NOW and put all subcategories in 1 table only.

Comment: And if you can't change the table design, create a view that does t2 union all t3.

Comment: If you can't change the database design, probably best to stop using  an RDBMS altogether.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Unfortunately it's part of a legacy application, but I'll try and join the subcategories in one table.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a new table for each subcategory. If you change that you only have two tables and simply can join them.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT c.Category,s.SubCategory
  FROM Table1 c
 LEFT JOIN 
       (
         SELECT * FROM Table2
         UNION ALL
         SELECT * FROM Table3
       ) s
   ON c.id = s.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

As I read from your question the subcategories are in different tables, so you could make a UNION (ALL) for these tables and then join to your Table1, like this

```
SELECT Table1.category, Table2.subcategory, Table3.subcategory  
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Table2.category_id, Table2.subcategory
           FROM   Table2
           UNION ALL
           SELECT Table3.category_id, Table3.subcategory
           FROM   Table3
          ) sub
ON Table1.id=sub.category_id
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: create some `VIEW`s to ensure you have data items named sensibly and consistently, which will make the query easier to write e.g.

```
CREATE VIEW Subcategories
AS 
SELECT subcategory, category_id
  FROM Table2
UNION
SELECT subcategory, category_id
  FROM Table3;


CREATE VIEW Categories
AS 
SELECT id AS category_id, category
  FROM Table1;


SELECT category, subcategory
  FROM Categories NATURAL JOIN Subcategories
UNION
SELECT category, 0 AS subcategory
  FROM Categories
 WHERE category_id NOT IN ( SELECT category_id 
                              FROM Subcategories );
```